# Text based battleship enemy AI not working as wanted - Java

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

Im making a text based battleship game and the player plays against the computer. 3 random 3 unit long ships are placed on the board, and I want the computer to be able to guess around where his last guess was if his last guess was a hit. (but I want it to work so that he keeps guessing around the same spot until he got a hit and keep guessing around there until he gets the whole ship, or 3 hits)
It works a bit; the computer will guess near his last guess if it was a hit, but if he misses that guess then he starts guessing randomly again. Can someone help me out a bit?
-getGuess() method is the one with the AI-

```
/*
 * computer class to handle computers guesses/ etc
 * most methods are copied from player class, but slightly altered to account for variable names
 * Methods that havent been copied have comments
 */ 

public class Computer{
  static int firstCo, secondCo;
  static int[] guessedHits={7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7};
  //int array to store last guess
  static int[] lastGuess = new int[2];
  //int array to store current guess
  static int[] guess=new int[2];

  public static int[] computerShip1=new int[6];
  public static int[] computerShip2=new int[6];
  public static int[] computerShip3=new int[6];

  /*
   * method to choose random guess for computer - but make it guess around last guess if last guess was a hit
   * return guess coordinate numbers in an array
   */
  public static int[] getGuess(){
    int[] guess=new int[2];
    int firstCo, secCo;
    int ran; //random int between 0 and 1 - will help to make random choices for guesses
    if(isHit(lastGuess[0],lastGuess[1])){
      ran=(int)(Math.random()*2);
      //if ran is 0 and last guesses x coordinate was correct, set next guess to last x, and next y to last y +1
      if((ran==0 && lastGuess[0]==Player.playerShip1[0]) || (ran==0 && lastGuess[0]==Player.playerShip1[2]) || (ran==0 && lastGuess[0]==Player.playerShip1[4])){
        guess[0]=lastGuess[0];
        guess[1]=lastGuess[1]+1;
      //if ran is 1 and last guesses x coordinate was correct, set next guess to last x, and next y to last y -1
      }else if((ran==1 && lastGuess[0]==Player.playerShip1[0]) || (ran==1 && lastGuess[0]==Player.playerShip1[2]) || (ran==1 && lastGuess[0]==Player.playerShip1[4])){
        guess[0]=lastGuess[0];
        guess[1]=lastGuess[1]-1;
      //if ran is 0 and last guesses y coordinate was correct, set next guess to last y, and next x to last x +1
      }else if((ran==0 && lastGuess[1]==Player.playerShip1[1]) || (ran==0 && lastGuess[1]==Player.playerShip1[3]) || (ran==0 && lastGuess[1]==Player.playerShip1[5])){
        guess[0]=lastGuess[0]+1;
        guess[1]=lastGuess[1];
      //if ran is 1 and last guesses y coordinate was correct, set next guess to last y, and next x to last x -1
      }else if((ran==1 && lastGuess[1]==Player.playerShip1[1]) || (ran==1 && lastGuess[1]==Player.playerShip1[3]) || (ran==1 && lastGuess[1]==Player.playerShip1[5])){
        guess[0]=lastGuess[0]-1;
        guess[1]=lastGuess[1];
      }
    return guess;
    }else{
      guess[0]=(int)(Math.random()*7);
      guess[1]=(int)(Math.random()*7);
      return guess;
    }
  }

  public static boolean isHit(int firstC, int secC){
    for(int i=0; i<Player.playerShip1.length; i=i+2){
      if(firstC==Player.playerShip1[i] && secC==Player.playerShip1[i+1]){
        return true;
      }
      if(i==4){
        break;
      }
      }
    for(int i=0; i<Player.playerShip2.length; i=i+2){
      if(firstC==Player.playerShip2[i] && secC==Player.playerShip2[i+1]){
        return true;
      }
        if(i==4){
        break;
        }
      }

    for(int i=0; i<Player.playerShip3.length; i=i+2){
      if(firstC==Player.playerShip3[i] && secC==Player.playerShip3[i+1]){
        return true;
      }
      if(i==4){
        break;
      }
      }

    return false;
  }


  public static void addHits(int firstC, int secC){
    int index=-1;
    for(int i=0; i<guessedHits.length; i++){
      if(guessedHits[i]==7){
        index=i;
        break;
      }
    }
    guessedHits[index]=firstC;
    guessedHits[index+1]=secC;
  }


  public static void setComputerShips(){
   int randX, randY;
   int direction; //will be random int 0-1, determines direction ship will extend(up/down, left/right)

   randX=(int)(Math.random()*7);
   randY=(int)(Math.random()*7);
   direction=(int)(Math.random()*2);

   computerShip1[0]=randX;
   computerShip1[1]=randY;
   if(direction==0){//extend upwards or downwards 2 units(y values change, x stays the same)
    computerShip1[2]=randX;
    computerShip1[4]=randX;
    if(randY>3){//if y value is greater than 3, has to extend down or it wont fit
     computerShip1[3]=randY-1;
     computerShip1[5]=randY-2;
    }else if(randY<2){//if y value is less than 2, has to extend up or it wont fit
     computerShip1[3]=randY+1;
     computerShip1[5]=randY+2;
    }else{//if direction doesnt matter, just extend upwards
     computerShip1[3]=randY+1;
     computerShip1[5]=randY+2;
    }
   }else if(direction==1){//extends left or right 2 units(y values stay the same, x changes)
    computerShip1[3]=randY;
    computerShip1[5]=randY;
    if(randX>3){//if x is greater than 3, must extend left or it wont fit
     computerShip1[2]=randX-1;
     computerShip1[4]=randX-2;
    }else if(randX<2){//if x is less than 2, must extend right or it wont fit
     computerShip1[2]=randX+1;
     computerShip1[4]=randX+2;
    }else{//if direction doesnt matter, just extend right
     computerShip1[2]=randX+1;
     computerShip1[4]=randX+2;
    }
   }
   //do same for both other ships
   do{
   randX=(int)(Math.random()*7);
   randY=(int)(Math.random()*7);
   }while((randX==computerShip1[0] && randY==computerShip1[1])||(randX==computerShip1[2]&&randY==computerShip1[3])||(randX==computerShip1[4]&&randY==computerShip1[5]));
   direction=(int)(Math.random()*2);

   computerShip2[0]=randX;
   computerShip2[1]=randY;
   if(direction==0){
    computerShip2[2]=randX;
    computerShip2[4]=randX;
    if(randY>3){
     computerShip2[3]=randY-1;
     computerShip2[5]=randY-2;
    }else if(randY<2){
     computerShip2[3]=randY+1;
     computerShip2[5]=randY+2;
    }else{
     computerShip2[3]=randY+1;
     computerShip2[5]=randY+2;
    }
   }else if(direction==1){
    computerShip2[3]=randY;
    computerShip2[5]=randY;
    if(randX>3){
     computerShip2[2]=randX-1;
     computerShip2[4]=randX-2;
    }else if(randX<2){
     computerShip2[2]=randX+1;
     computerShip2[4]=randX+2;
    }else{
     computerShip2[2]=randX+1;
     computerShip2[4]=randX+2;
    }
   }
   do{
   randX=(int)(Math.random()*7);
   randY=(int)(Math.random()*7);
   }while((randX==computerShip1[0] && randY==computerShip1[1])||(randX==computerShip1[2]&&randY==computerShip1[3])||(randX==computerShip1[4]&&randY==computerShip1[5])||(randX==computerShip2[0] && randY==computerShip2[1])||(randX==computerShip2[2]&&randY==computerShip2[3])||(randX==computerShip2[4]&&randY==computerShip2[5]));
   direction=(int)(Math.random()*2);

   computerShip3[0]=randX;
   computerShip3[1]=randY;
   if(direction==0){
    computerShip3[2]=randX;
    computerShip3[4]=randX;
    if(randY>3){
     computerShip3[3]=randY-1;
     computerShip3[5]=randY-2;
    }else if(randY<2){
     computerShip3[3]=randY+1;
     computerShip3[5]=randY+2;
    }else{
     computerShip3[3]=randY+1;
     computerShip3[5]=randY+2;
    }
   }else if(direction==1){
    computerShip3[3]=randY;
    computerShip3[5]=randY;
    if(randX>3){
     computerShip3[2]=randX-1;
     computerShip3[4]=randX-2;
    }else if(randX<2){
     computerShip3[2]=randX+1;
     computerShip3[4]=randX+2;
    }else{
     computerShip3[2]=randX+1;
     computerShip3[4]=randX+2;
    }
   }
  }

  public static boolean hasWon(){
    if(guessedHits[17]!=7)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me, that I already seen such question some days ago. This is common homework for your class?

Comment: Yes! I found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353208/text-based-battleship-game-printing-two-of-the-same-grids-java

Answer (score 1):

Your getGuess() function is the one you're after right?

1) You never account for times when you guess the same spot twice. Make a boolean value that determines whether the coordinates you're attempting to guess haven't already been guessed.

2) Your method of keeping ship coordinates is very awkward where 0,2,4 are X coords while 1,3,5 are Y coords? You're better off creating a `Ship` class that handles coordinates, and checks like isHit.

```
public class Ship {
    int[] xCoords = new int[3];
    int[] yCoords = new int[3];

    public boolean isHit(int x, int y) {
      return (Arrays.asList(xCoords).contains(x) && Arrays.asList(yCoords).contains(y));
    }
}
```

Then you can:

```
if (Player.ship1.isHit(guess[0],guess[1])) {
  ....
}
```

At the very heart of it you have a little ways to go. You'll get better responses here if you start working at the problem then come back with specific problems you may have. Try to be as concise as possible when giving code snippets because not many people will spend much time going through an entire class to find a line or two giving issues.

Good luck!

---PS---

I wrote a battleship game about 3-4 years ago with some fairly advanced AI. I'll link it here:

https://github.com/GrahamBlanshard/AI-Battleship/blob/master/prograham/battleship/player/AIPlayer.java

First, I apologize for the... lame code (I was a much younger programmer, I swear!). If you want to view it to get hints that is fine. A brief explanation:

At the heart of it you need to create some form of datatype that stores his hits. Once a "hit" is scored you push it to the datatype, I used a `Stack`. The shots that are successful hits get stored on the stack until the ship is sunk. At that point it removes shots from the stack that belonged to the ship that just sunk. If there are shots still on the stack it knows it has hit a second ship during that process and continues to guess in the area.

To accomplish this, it goes through phases:

1) Shoot randomly until a hit.

2) Shoot around that shot (use a random(4) call to get N/S/E/W direction)
-- Keep doing this until you score a second shot

3) Create a "line" with the two points and fire along it until the ship sinks or...

4) Reverse the line and shoot the other direction.

Does that give you a good start to work with?

Comment: woah thanks for such a detailed answer, this helped a lot! thanks, Im gunna start working on it now

Comment: No problem. I could write pages about it; one of the first "big" projects I actually took on during my university career. I revisited it later on to add better AI (the probablility function that is called in the accessMap() function). Do your best, get one thing to work then branch out from there.

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code to look at. So for now I will give some general suggestions that come to mind:

When the computer AI gets a "hit", set a "global" flag (more likely a class variable) and "remember" where the hit occured. On the following turns, guess the neighboring squares in some predetermined order (say north, south, east, west) until another hit is found. Then set another flag and on the next turn guess in the same direction as the second hit. The initial flag should only be reset when all three hits are found. This should fix the problem that a subsequent miss causes the computer AI to start guessing randomly again.